Strategy Related questions
Is there a way to delineate what constitutes value-added in terms of strategy related questions and what is merely asking others to do the grunt work in terms of strategy profiling and idea generation? I think most recently more and more of the same type of questions are popping up and to be honest I find most a mismatch with the intentions of this site. Asking others to do your work seems inappropriate, which equally applies to homework type of questions. But my point here are strategy related questions. 
The most recent example is the following, which I find a borderline case:
Pairs trading: Question on non-negative profits, size of the positions and trading signals
Any views?
